# graphite, use regular expressions to select the target, or an alternative

Tags: graphite

I need to query graphite for data with a few different targets;
currently I do a http query for each target. for instance:

```
http://graphite.example.com/render/?format=json&until=now&from=-1min&target=servers.srv231.solr.hits
http://graphite.example.com/render/?format=json&until=now&from=-1min&target=servers.srv325.solr.hits
```

Is there a way to get the two results in one query?
I could do as follows:

```
http://graphite.example.com/render/?format=json&until=now&from=-1min&target=servers.srv*.solr.hits
```

but I would get a lot of other data that I am not interested in.

i've tried using regular expressions, like this, but it does not work:

```
http://graphite.example.com/render/?format=json&until=now&from=-1min&target=servers.srv(231|325).solr.hits
```

In the doc, they do not mention regular expressions nor wildcards,
but they use wildcards in the examples.
http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/render_api.html

is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I just saw that the `target` parameter can be repeated multiple times, so I could do http://graphite.example.com/render/?format=json&until=now&from=-1min&target=servers.srv231.solr.hits&target=servers.srv325.solr.hits. that's ok for me. however, is it still possible to use regular expressions or a more concise way?

Answer (score 8):

Graphite uses globs not regular expressions for matching. So your query would be:

```
http://graphite.example.com/render/?format=json&until=now&from=-1min&target=servers.srv{231,325}.solr.hits
```

Comment: it works, thanks! is there a reference about the glob pattern? this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming) does not include the brackets {}. this one has: http://linux.die.net/Linux-CLI/x11655.htm  or maybe there is not a standard one? i didn't find a doc about glob in graphite.

Comment: As graphite is a python app, I'm guessing that it uses the python [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module, which would pretty much be the same as [your link](http://linux.die.net/Linux-CLI/x11655.htm) to linux.die.net, which all looks like what I've used with graphite before.

Comment: the link to the python glob module does not mention curly brackets {}. i see that there is a patch for supporting curly brackets in python glob http://bugs.python.org/issue9584  but it seems that it is not in the current implementation, and i don't find it documented in the python glob module. ??